# PHP insert Tag CSS in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
$array = array('[one] => Array ( [count] => 2 )', '[two] => Array ( [count] => 2 )', '[three] => Array ( [count] => 2 )');
```

result;

```
<span class="red"> one <em>(2)</em></span>
<span class="red"> two <em>(2)</em></span>
<span class="red"> three <em>(3)</em></span>
```

Comment: what do you mean by insert tag css in array?

Comment: You need to explain what your question is.

Comment: Simply use `foreach` loop over here

Comment: I have an array, extracted from a mysql DB.
$array = array (
'[one] => Array ([count] => 2)',
'[two] => Array ([count] => 2)',
'[three] => Array ([count] => 2)'
);

I must add tags to CSS PHP code, as in result
<span class = "red"> one <em> (2) </ em> </ span>
<span class = "red"> two <em> (2) </ em> </ span>
<span class = "red"> three <em> (3) </ em> </ span>

Comment: an incomplete question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got your question then you might be looking for the following thing

```
$array = array('one' => Array ( 'count' => 2 ), 'two' => Array ( 'count' => 2 ), 'three' => Array ( 'count' => 2 ));

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "<span class='red'> $key <em>({$value['count']})</em></span><br/>";
}
```

Comment: You can accept it as an answer

Comment: It is what I was looking, for work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach key and value 
sample:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
echo "<span class='red'> $key <em>({$value['count']})</em></span><br/>";
```

}